# Need software that can help me in working with pixels

Tags: c, graphics, pixel

I am working with graphics in C. I find thinking about the pixel locations terrible and I am in need of a tool where I can draw images and it gives me the pixel location of that point. Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paint that comes with Windows provides pixel locations in its status bar.

Comment: Thats really nice.I was actually working with paint for the graphics but I never saw the pixels before.Thanks

Comment: @fahad: Paint also has a zoom feature (the magnifying glass in the tool box) that when set to the maximum can really help for pixel-level detail work.

Answer (score 2):

Check out free and open source gimp http://www.gimp.org/ . It is the most highly rated open source multi os paint program by far.

Comment: While this is certainly a valid suggestion, it seems to me a little like killing flies with a sledgehammer. Not to mention that most people who are not graphics professionals find the GIMP's interface supremely unintuitive, and for those of us who know Photoshop well, it seems like a poor imitation.

Comment: @Cody true. but fahad didn't mention he was on windows or linux. And there was only one tool I know of that works on both and has this feature. Otherwise I would just mention mspaint :)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the OS,its Windows : )

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here, however, [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) allows you to position and draw things on a per-pixel basis. You could draw your graphics, etc on Inkscape and use that as a reference.

Also, as Basarat Ali says, GIMP is good for this too.